# summarizing video using matlab

Tags: matlab, memory, video, image-processing, summarization

I want to load a video in matlab and summarize it. The video I have taken is medical video and length is 3 minutes with more than 5000 frames. I am not able to load the entire video. Getting not enough memory error in matlab. For summarization I need atleast 2 minute video so that the output is for 40 seconds

I've used the following code.
Only 200 frames are read. I want to read more frames.

```
xyloObj = VideoReader(filename);
vid = read(xyloObj,[1 200]);
```

Help me out.

Answer (score 0):

There is a note in the documentation stating that `read` will be removed from the next version of Matlab:

> **Note:**   VideoReader.read will be removed in a future release. Use VideoReader.readFrame instead.

It is not exactly clear what summary you want to do from your video, but you can read all frame sequentially using:

```
xyloObj = VideoReader('xylophone.mp4');
mov = struct('cdata',zeros(vidHeight,vidWidth,3,'uint8'),'colormap',[]);
k = 1;
while hasFrame(xyloObj)
    mov(k).cdata = readFrame(xyloObj);
    k = k+1;
end
```

This is just the example from the matlab documentation found [here](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreader.readframe.html).